# echart line charts - how to remove series line markers

Tags: echarts

Plotting a series line with Baidu's echarts library, does anyone here know how to remove the x-axis tick marker (the small circles on the line - see screenshot below)?

[screenshot (unable to embed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KTkC.png)

I can't find an option in the series line type https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-line.type

edit: here's a simple [example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/touring/3L4g5qkh/)

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('container'));

myChart.setOption(option = {
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
},
series: [{
    data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
    type: 'line'
}]
});

window.onresize = function() {
myChart.resize();
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :) In Order to help other people understand your problem, please add a minimal code example to clarify you issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess the option you are looking for is showSymbol in series. Set it to false.

```
series: [{
   data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
   showSymbol: false,
   type: 'line'
}]
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr1ap9bx/)

Comment: thank you!! work well